# Can an optimization algorithm be "universal"?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraint-satisfaction, sat-solvers, quadratic-programming

I am wondering if a Bayesian Optimization framework (e.g. Google's Vizier) can be used in lieu of a traditional solver like Gurobi or CPLEX.

In trying to answer this question, I realized that I don't know enough about optimization theory to answer a more general question: Just how interchangeable are heuristic approaches for solving computationally hard optimization problems?

Coming from an ML background, I'm reasoning by analogy with supervised learning problems: In ML, some methods like Neural Networks (with a sufficient number of layers) or Support Vector Machines are universal, in that they can approximate any shape decision boundary or regression function up to an arbitrary level of precision.

Are there equivalent algorithms in optimization theory that can be used to solve any optimization problem (linear, non-linear, continuous, discrete, etc...), e.g. can Genetic Algorithms or Particle Swarm Optimization be thrown at *any* optimization problem and give us a reasonable solution? SGD is used to solve NP-Complete problems (i.e. training a neural network) - does that mean that it can be used for any optimization problem?

I assume that the reverse is true: Not all optimization are universal, for example methods that work for LP or QP don't necessarily work for harder problems.

If it is indeed the case that some optimization algorithms are universal, is Bayesian Optimization one of these universal algorithms? Can be used to approach LP, QP, MIP, TSP, and NP-Hard problems in general?

Comment: What do you mean by "solve" ? Find an optimal solution within reasonable time? Find a reasonable solution within reasonable time? Find an optimal solution within any time at all? Also, there is no algorithm for solving (for almost all meanings of "solve") _all_ NP-hard problems, as this class includes problems that are undecidable. Maybe you want to consider NP-_complete_ problems instead?

Comment: @Discretelizard I meant "Find a reasonable solution within reasonable time" - for average case real world problems. I understand that some NP-hard problems will be difficult to solve, but assume there is an average case complexity consideration that makes some algorithms generally applicable?

Comment: Ok, then I think I see what you mean by "solve". The problem with considering all NP-hard problems is that the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is an NP-hard problem. Under standard assumptions on the capabilities of computers, there cannot exists an algorithm that gives valid solution to the Halting problem, no matter how much time or resources it has (this is what it means for a problem to be _undecidable_ ).

Comment: Deep networks are not a panacea. Consider for example navigation apps like Google maps or Waze. They use dedicated shortest path algorithms. Similarly, SAT solvers use dedicated algorithms. The advantage of general-purpose algorithms is that they might work even if a special-purpose algorithm doesn't exist.

Comment: In the discrete and bounded setting, exhaustive search is guaranteed to find the best solution. In this sense, universal algorithms do exist, but they are typically not very useful. Deep learning is a heuristic which works well on some problems, and not as well on others.

Comment: @Discretelizard the halting problem is not NP-hard, is just undecidable, isn't? In my understanding, undecidable problems are outside the study of complexity, because it rather belongs to the study of computability.

Comment: @Peregring-lk The definition of NP-hardness I'm aware of is that a decision problem A is NP-hard if all problems in NP can be reduced to A in polynomial time. A problem can be both undecidable and NP-hard. [The Halting problem is such a problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness#Examples).

Comment: It is true that the goal of complexity theory is to obtain a more fine-grained classification of computational problems than just computability, but it doesn't make sense to restrict yourself to decidable problems a priori. One reason for this is that we don't always know if a complexity class contains undecidable problems when we define it, see [here](https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:A#all) for a few examples.

Answer (score 2):

Even if there were, remember that there is [no free lunch in search and optimization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization). An optimization algorithm *necessarily* trades proficiency in one class of problems for inefficiency in another class of problems. This is related to why the fact that neural networks, SVMs, and even the humble step function are "universal" is of little practical import.

Even within a specific class of optimization problem— say, linear programming— it is well known that a general, off-the-shelf optimizer e.g. Gurobi isn't likely going to do as well as some specialized optimizer tailored to your use case, should one be available (of course, frequently, there isn't one, which is why general purpose optimizers exist).

Answer (score 1):

There is no heuristic that is "universal" in practice.  Which heuristic works best in practice often depends on the specific problem you're dealing with.  There's no one "silver bullet" heuristic that works great on every optimization problem.

Comment: Isn't all NP-hard problems reducible to non-linear programming? I know that a lot of NP-hard problems are reducible to integer linear programming; I remember even reading that the simplex algorithm (which I know, it's for LP, not ILP), was called NP-mighty or something like that, meaning that any NP-complete problem instance belongs to the lineal programming problem, and it's solvable using the simplex algorithm; I don't know at which extent a similar affirmation can be stated about NP-hard problems though.

Comment: @Peregring-lk, No.  All NP-complete problems are reducible to integer linear programming, but that's not a very useful statement, as the same is true if you replace ILP with any other NP-complete problem. The simplex algorithm is not a state-of-the-art method for ILP.  None of this changes my statements in my answer.